# Signature on LaTex lines

Tags: signatures

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % or "brazilian"

\newcommand\namegroup[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w0bR.png){%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \vspace*{1.5cm}  % leave some space above the horizontal line
        \hrule
        \vspace{1mm} % just a bit more whitespace below the line
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
            #1
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

```
APROVADO: 5 de Dezembro de 2017.

\begin{center}
    \namegroup{Prof.$^a$ Daniele Cristiane Menezes\\(UFV)}
    \hspace{1.5cm}
    \namegroup{Prof.$^a$ Rita de Cássia Superbi de Sousa\\(UFV)}

    \namegroup{Prof. Emilio Borges\\(Orientador)\\(UFV)}
    \hspace{1.5cm}
    \namegroup{Prof.$^a$ Rejane de Castro Santana\\ (Presidente da banca e coordenadora da disciplina) \\(UFV)}


\end{center}
```

\end{document}[image]

Comment: Lines like that are meant for forms wich are often machine-read. I guess all the people signing will have a general understanding on why and what they sign. If they don't know, just show them by pointing with your finger. I absolutely hate lines like that. Off topic, the lines are badly aligned.

Comment: \newcommand\namegroup[1]{%
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}    \hrule
  \vspace{1mm} 
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
   #1
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

 APROVADO.
 
 \begin{center}
  \namegroup{Prof.$^a$ Daniele Cristiane Menezes\\(UFV)}
  \hspace{1.5cm}
  \namegroup{Prof.$^a$ Rita de Cássia Superbi de Sousa\\(UFV)}
  
  \namegroup{Prof. Emilio Borges\\(Orientador)\\(UFV)}
  \hspace{1.5cm}
  \namegroup{Prof.$^a$ Rejane de Castro Santana\\ (Presidente da banca e coordenadora da disciplina) \\(UFV)}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest setting up a macro that outputs a fixed-width `minipage` environment, consisting of a horizontal line and the name, role, and affiliation of one person.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % or "brazilian"
\usepackage{helvet} % just for this example

\newcommand\namegroup[1]{%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
   \vspace*{1.5cm}  % leave some space above the horizontal line
   \hrule
   \vspace{1mm} % just a bit more whitespace below the line
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
   #1
   \end{tabular}
   \end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\sffamily % just for this example


APROVADA: 30 de abril de 2011.

\begin{center}
\namegroup{Prof. José Carlos Almeida\\(Coorientador)\\(UFV)}
\hspace{1.5cm}
\namegroup{Prof. Mario Dias Silva\\(Coorientador)\\(UFV)}

\namegroup{Prof. Maria Clara Paiva\\(UFV)}
\hspace{1.5cm}
\namegroup{Prof. Marina Gomes\\(UFV)}

\namegroup{Prof. Jo{\~a}o Silva Neto\\(Orientador)\\(UFV)}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I add a clumsy but working solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 $\overline{\qquad\text{Prof.\ Jos\'e Carlos Almeda}\qquad}$ \quad& \quad
 $\overline{\qquad\text{Prof.\ Jos\'e Carlos Almeda}\qquad}$ \\
 (Coorientador) &  (Coorientador) \\
 (UFW) & (UFW) \\[1cm]
 $\overline{\qquad\text{Prof.\ Jos\'e Carlos Almeda}\qquad}$ \quad& \quad
 $\overline{\qquad\text{Prof.\ Jos\'e Carlos Almeda}\qquad}$ \\
 (Coorientador) &  (Coorientador) \\
 (UFW) & (UFW) 
\end{tabular}\\[1cm]
$\overline{\qquad\text{Prof.\ Jos\'e Carlos Almeda}\qquad}$\\
(Coorientador) \\
(UFW)
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I did not copy your names, rather just used one over and over. Much more elegant solutions can be found e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303590/creating-a-right-aligned-signature-block?rq=1).